# static methods that return an instance of an object but behave like a constructor

Tags: language-agnostic, constructor

So I have an object that can be constructed in a few ways.  The constructors have signatures like, the one that loads an object from a file:

```
Object::Object( string filenameToLoadFrom ) ;
```

And how it behaves is pretty straightforward.

```
Object( "filename.dat" ) ; // loads object from filename
```

The constructor signature pretty much says what it does, although a static method `Load` might arguably be better:

```
static Object* Object::Load( string filenameToLoadFrom ) ;
```

<sub>(syntax above is slightly incorrect but you get the idea.)</sub>

Then we come into cases where what the constructor does *isn't immediately obvious* from the parameters.  *a name is needed* to make it clear from the API what the constructor does.

The question is, is it a good idea to write static methods that return an instance of the object, just for the sake of being able to name the constructor?

Comment: no it s not a good idea to have static factories. how many files do you have? why dont you look at DI?

Comment: @DarthVader [Could you be more specific?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DI)

Comment: why do you need static factories to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually considered a common [secondary benefit of the Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Other_benefits_and_variants).  It is potentially useful in specific scenarios, especially for things where you have the same argument type providing very different meanings.

For example, it's not uncommon to have a class representing an "Angle" which can be constructed by a single floating point number which could represent degrees or radians.  Constructors do not provide enough context (or a clean way) to implement this, where a "factory method" makes this very clear.

Comment: Interestingly, this is called the [Named Constructor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-ctor-idiom.html).  Named constructors also have the advantage of being able [to return NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859062/can-a-constructor-return-a-null-value) in case of failure

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a good idea especially if you need more than one constructor that both take the same type of parameter(s). For example: static Object* loadFromFile( String fileName) and statc Object* loadFromResorce(String resourceName). You can even make the actual constructor private to enforce the use of the static constructors.